# App Engine not showing static file directory in Debugger Source view

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I inherited a App Engine static-file-only service and I am still trying to understand it (contract developers, long gone, docs=0). One point that I am stuck on is why in the Debugger Source display I don't see the static file directory. This is a Python 2.7 app and to be clear there is no Python code provided. The app.yaml file looks like this:

```
service ya-da
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
```

It is a SPA, so it just one html file and lots of bundled JS & CSS.

This is what I see in App Engine Debugger source display

[image]

So no dist directory is shown. But it is there as the app is running happily. There is nothing tucked into any other directory (most of them are utterly useless in the App Engine context) that would be the contents of dist.

So, the simple question is: why doesn't dist show up in the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

given that you have found an issue related with the debugger, you can file an issue in the Public Issue Tracker of Google Cloud Platform with the components of Debugger Stackdriver [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187252&template=0). In this way, the Stackdriver Engineers team have visibility of this issue and other users with the same issue can star it and follow it.

Comment: That URL seems to land on an internal Google site. I don't have a Google Moma SSO.

Comment: I suspect that this is intended behavior and not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment to my other answer, it seems you just need access to code that was deployed.

It looks like you are using GAE standard first generation so you should be able to download your code as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/downloading-source-code).  This is the command:

```
appcfg.py -A [YOUR_PROJECT_ID] -V [YOUR_VERSION_ID] download_app [OUTPUT_DIR]
```

That page has deprecation warnings because Google is encouraging people to migrate to GAE second generation, but I expect that will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Your static files don't show up in the debugger because GAE treats static files very differently than it does your code.

The point of having static files is to be able to serve them without burdening your GAE instances.  The `app.yaml` file has a an `upload` option because you are telling GAE where to put your static files, and this location is separate from where your code is uploaded.

The debugger is for debugging code.  It is not possible to debug a static file because there is no code (Well, no server code.  Your Javascript runs in the browser.) and there is nothing to debug.

What is it you are trying to accomplish?  Your Javascript is running on the front end so you can't debug it on the backend.

Comment: I don't want to debug static files, but I want to see them in the Source listing. An answer that was here yesterday, but apparently deleted, gave the working functionality in the case of using a "static" directory. In my case, "dist" is not showing up.

Comment: @KevinBuchs, static files are not source code so they don't show up there.  Is the problem that you don't have copies of the static files and need to download them all?  Please let us know more about the problem so we can try to help.

Comment: What you are saying does not make much sense. In the static files directory are .js files. How would Stackdriver Debugger know what is static and what isn't. All the app.yaml references is a single html file in the dist directory.

Comment: I would like to verify what is actually present in the dist directory. I am having trouble rebuilding it from source.

Comment: @KevinBuchs, your `app.yaml` file indicates which files are static.  The ones that are static never reach the debugger.  But see my other answer in case that helps.

Comment: The app.yaml only indicates that index.html is static. There are other files that are referenced by that file which are also static.